# Can $\mathbb R$ be written as $(-\infty , \infty)$?

Tags: soft-question, notation, real-numbers, infinity

I was thinking about if $\mathbb R$ could be written as $(-\infty , \infty)$. I'm not sure if it's okay, because I've read somewhere (I can't remember where) that $(-\infty , \infty)$ declares **extended real line**, which is totally different from $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Where you read that are more probably write...but it is a matter of agreement. Better, write $\;\Bbb R=(-\infty,\,\infty)\;$ . I don't think anyone dealing with mathematics will misunderstand that.

Comment: Is it okay to write ??@DonAntonio

Comment: You can write it, its just more work and more to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Although it's unusual, it makes sense to write $\mathbb R$ as $(-\infty,\infty)$. That would never be the extended real line, which would be denoted by $[-\infty,\infty]$.

Comment: But can $\infty$ be included in closed brackets ?? I mean, $\infty$ is not a number, how can it be an element of a set ??

Comment: In extended real line, $\infty$ is a number (though it's not a real number).

Comment: And $\emptyset$ is not a number either, but we write $\{\emptyset\}$, don't we? Besides, we are talking about the **extended** real line here, right?! Therefore, it is supposed to contain something else besides the real numbers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: $\{\emptyset\}$ is really another case. That is the *set*  containing the empty set, we can have sets of anything.

Comment: Got it. Thanks !!

Comment: @AnikBhowmick I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

It *can* be written that way, it doesn't mean it should be.

Have you ever heard of "complex infinity" or "directionless infinity"? Your readers would quickly realize you're not referring to either of those, but it could still be enough to cause a little cognitive dissonance and disrupt the flow of your presentation.

If you don't like $\mathbb R$ for whatever reason, you can always use $\textbf R$ instead. You don't lose any clarity that way.

Comment: What's the difference between the two $R$'s?

Comment: @goblin Is this one of those you already know but you're checking if I know?

Comment: No I haven't heard any of them. And besides of that, what does *$R$* denote ??

Comment: Nope. I haven't seen the distinction . Math notation isn't totally consistent if course, and what one of us considers standard may be unfamiliar to the other

Comment: $\mathbb R$ is blackboard bold for the set of reals, $\textbf R$ is for the set of reals for people who think blackboard bold is for the blackboard only, and $R$ can mean whatever you want it to mean just as long as you say what that is.

Comment: @RobertSoupe, fair enough. I thought maybe you were proposing that $\mathbf{R}$ be used for the affinely extended real line, or perhaps the projectively extended one.